# ¿Como hacer redirección 301 en IIS cuando el dominio antiguo y apunta a la nueva web?

Tags: iis, redirección, seo

Necesito hacer una redirección 301 permanente en un servidor IIS y he encontrado buscando en internet lo siguiente:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://foo.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
```

mi duda es que mi dominio antiguo ya apunta hacia el nuevo servidor, entonces si añado esto no podré acceder a las páginas de interior por que se redireccionará siempre a la que ponga yo en destination.
Como ya dije el dominio antiguo ya me apunta hacia el nuevo, pero no mediante una redirección 301 como yo quiero, porque lo necesito por posicionamiento porque el dominio antiguo va a desaparecer

Comment: Esta en ingles, pero quizá te sirva http://semanticmastery.com/redirecting-links-from-an-expired-domains